# How to convert Strings into Bytes in Python2?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, byte, python-2.x

I'm trying to convert a string into bytes and those bytes must be in a string type. I know how to do that in pyhon3, it is pretty straight forward, but in python2 I'm just lost :(

I've tried the encode() function in python2 but it doesn't seem to work, I've read there is no such thing as byte type in python2 so that maybe the case why I'm failing.

Anyways, I wrote this code in python3 and it is working flawlessy:

```py
>>> a="hey"
>>> b=bytes(a, 'utf-8')
>>> print(b)
b'hey'
>>> type(b)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> c=''
>>> for i in b:
...     c+=str(i)+" "
...
>>>
>>> print (c)
104 101 121
```

Instead with python2 I've tryed, of course bytes(a, 'utf-8') but it's saying str() takes exactly one argument (2 given).
Then I've tryed encode() and bytearray() but no luck with those either.

If you have any hints on how to get the representing bytes `104 101 121` of `ehy` in python2, or if you know for sure that this "conversion" is not possible please let me know.

Comment: `bytes` doesn't exist in Python 2, or rather, Python 2 `str` is the equivalent of Python 3 `bytes` (so no conversion necessary), and Python 2 unicode is equivalent to Python 3 `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for such a conversion in Python 2, since `bytes` is just an alias to `str` in Python 2.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3112-byte-literals):

> Python 2.6 adds `bytes` as a *synonym* for
>   the `str` type, and it also supports the
>   `b''` notation.
>
> The 2.6 `str` differs from 3.0’s bytes
>   type in various ways; most notably,
>   the constructor is completely
>   different. In 3.0, `bytes([65, 66, 67])`
>   is 3 elements long, containing the
>   bytes representing `ABC`; in 2.6,
>   `bytes([65, 66, 67])` returns the
>   12-byte string representing the `str()`
>   of the list.
>
> The primary use of `bytes` in 2.6 will
>   be to write tests of object type such
>   as `isinstance(x, bytes)`. This will
>   help the `2to3` converter, which can’t
>   tell whether 2.x code intends strings
>   to contain either characters or 8-bit
>   bytes; you can now use either `bytes` or
>   `str` to represent your intention
>   exactly, and the resulting code will
>   also be correct in Python 3.0.

If you want the Python 3 behavior of `bytes` in Python 2 in terms of being able to iterate through the bytes as integers, you can convert the string to `bytearray` instead (just keep in mind that `bytearray`, unlike `str` and `bytes`, is mutable):

```
>>> a = 'hey'
>>> b = bytearray(a)
>>> c = ''
>>> for i in b:
...     c += str(i) + ' '
...
>>> print(c)
104 101 121
```

Alternatively, you can use the `ord` function to convert each character to its ordinal number:

```
>>> for c in 'hey':
...     print ord(c)
...
104
101
121
```

Comment: That means that even if the variable type in python2 shows up as string I'll be able to get the representing bytes? `a="ehy"  isinstance(a,bytes) ` returns true which is comforting (not gonna lie :) ) but if i try to iterate over it, as expected, it is returning the chars `e h y ` and not the bytes representing it